# Range of values for $k$ if the equation $k(x^2+1)-1=x(x+6)$ has real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Range of values for $k$ if the equation $$k(x^2+1)-1=x(x+6)$$ has real roots. I tried letting $b^2-4ac$ equal to or be greater than 0 but not sure if that’s the way. Thanks.

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! This is the way to go. Just rearrange the quadratic and apply $b^2-4ac$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are on the right track. So, after rearranging the equation we get
$$\underbrace{(k-1)}_a x^2+\underbrace{(-6)}_bx+\underbrace{(k-1)}_c=0.$$
Therefore
$$b^2-4ac=(-6)^2-4(k-1)\cdot(k-1)=4(9-(k-1)^2)\geq 0.$$
What next?

P.S. As suggested by Michael Rozenberg, we should pay attention to the degenerate case when $k=1$ and therefore  $a=0$. 
In that case the equation is $-6x=0$ which has a real solution $x=0$.

Comment: I got 36-4k^2-4 is greater than or equal to 0, so 4k^2 is less than or equal to 32? Not sure if I’m doing it right

Comment: Please check the expansion of $(k-1)\cdot(k-1)=(k-1)^2$.

Comment: Yes I have it now!! Thanks so much

Comment: @Robert Z You can nor work with $b^2-4ac$ for $k=1$. Your solution is just wrong.

Comment: @Robert Z It not says that your way is true. We say about $b^2-4ac$ for $a\neq0$ only.

Comment: @Robert Z $b^2-ac$ has sense for quadratic equation only. For $a=0$ our equation is not quadratic equation.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I see your point. I edited the answer which explain the degenerate case.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$k=1+\frac{6x}{x^2+1}=1+\frac{6}{x+\frac{1}{x}}\leq1+\frac{6}{2}=4.$$
For $x=0$ we have $k=1$.

Thus, $1\leq k\leq4$ for $x\geq0.$

The case $x<0$ is the similar.

I got $-2\leq k\leq4$.

If you want to use $b^2-4ac$ so you need to make the following.

We need to find all reals $k$, for which the equation 
$$(k-1)x^2-6x+k-1=0$$ has real roots.

If $k=1$ we obtain $-6x=0,$ which has a root $0$, which says that $k=1$ is valid.

Now, let $k\neq1$.

Thus, since $b^2-4ac\geq0,$ we obtain
$$9-(k-1)^2\geq0,$$ which gives
$$-2\leq k\leq4$$ again.

Comment: So is that the answer?

Comment: Yes, it's the answer. Actually, you can not work with $b^2-4ac$ for $k=1$.

Comment: I have the strange feeling that, may be (who knows ?), you like (a little, may be) $AM-GM$. Am I correct ? (just kidding for sure). Cheers :-)

Comment: Yes, @Claude . I like to use and to prove inequalities. Just AM-GM it's the most used inequality.